# How to add a new page or start printing from the next page UWP?

Tags: c#, printing, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to print from my UWP app following this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app

Everything is working fine. But on a specific page, I want to escape the current page and start printing from the next page, ie, I want to add a page to the current one. I tried using the `RichTextBlockOverflow` element but failed. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Did you mean you just want to have more than one page for printing? Did the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) met  your requirements？

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained in details in [this blog post](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2016/10/25/a-recipe-for-printing-in-uwp-mvvm-apps/). I tried this code about a month ago and it worked nicely. It's using `UserControl` for general pages layout and than `RichTextBlock` for document layout (`Paragraphs` etc.).